# How can I delete a specific row from a jQuery generated table?

Tags: php, jquery, html, html-table, tablerow

Here's my code for generation of the table. I call it via jQuery and ajax.

```
echo '<table class="database-items table table-bordered">
<tbody>';
  foreach($stmt as $item){
  echo '
  <tr>
    <td>'.$item['title'].'</td>
    <td>
      <img src="wp-content/themes/twentyeleven-child/'.$item['image_path'].'" alt="">
    </td>
    <td>'.$item['asin'].'</td>
    <td>'.$item['weight'].'</td>
    <td>'.$item['dimension'].'</td>
    <td>'.$item['category'].'</td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btnDeleteitem" alt="'.$item['asin'].'">
        <i class="icon-remove"></i>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>';
  }
  echo '</tbody>
  </table>';
```

And if I click the `btnDeleteItem button`, I want to remove that row, the values will be based on it's `td` with `$item['asin']`

Here's my jquery for btnDeleteItem but I don't know how what to put inside

```
$('.btnDeleteitem').live('click', function() {
  //what to put here?
}
```

Comment: why not `on` instead of `live` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the button's [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) `tr` ancestor an remove it

```
$('.btnDeleteitem').live('click', function() {
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

Since [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for event deligation

```
$(document/* or closest existing ancestor of .btnDeleteitem*/).on('click', '.btnDeleteitem', function() {
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

Comment: The jQuery .live() method has been deprecated since November 2011. There is no reason to use it (unless you're stuck in the dark ages) so it's time to move on and let .live() die.http://liveisdeprecated.com/

Comment: so what is better to use? because it will not work if i use .click()